# Real time storage for mutiple ISCSI Initiators

Tags: windows-server-2016, iscsi

I have 3 Window Servers that acts as an initiators that connect to a same target through ISCSI and gain storage from it. Is there anyway to, if one server change the storage data, other can see and benefit from the change in real time too without have to reconnect to the target again?

Sorry for my bad English, tks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow concurrent access to the very same LUN you *must use a clustering filesystem* - if you don't, caching at the initiators *will destroy your data*.

For Windows, that's called *Cluster Shared Volume* (CSV). You need to install the *Failover Clustering* feature to configure that.

Comment: thank you! You saved me again :)))

Comment: May i ask is there a way to "hot spare" a CSV: like we can only see 1 CSV, but when that one is down then the other can take it place and keep things running like normal?

Comment: You can't hot-spare a whole volume that way. You have redundancy at the LUN/target level (RAID, redundant controllers) and at the path level (using iSCSI/Ethernet, FC or SAS with several paths and a load-balancing/failover scheme).